# Regex for valid mention detection in the given scenario

Tags: .net, regex, .net-core

I would like to detect mentions for usernames containing alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores. I'm currently using the following regex:

```
\b*@[a-zA-z0-9_-]+\b
```

It works fine for simple scenarios, but matches both `@nomatch` entries in the following text:

> ***@match***,
>
> Check out this link! https://someurl.com/@nomatch/test. This is some
>   text and some more text and some more text.
>
> What will it do with myemail@nomatch.net?
>
> This is a mention for ***@match***. This is another mention for, ***@MaTch***.
>   ***@__ma-tch__*** is awesome. So is ***@--match--***, ***@ma_tch***, and ***@_MATCH***.
>
> And let's not forget ***@__match__***.
>
> Sincerely, ***@match***

I've tried my hand at writing more sophisticated regular expressions for this, but for every case I fix, I end up breaking another case.

Considering the above text, what would be a regular expression that would match all `@match` (with dash and underscore variations) entries, but not match the `@nomatch` entries?

Edit: Italicized desired matches for clarity. The regex engine is .NET Core, language C#.

Comment: Note `\b*` makes no sense anyway. What did you intend to match with it? Do you want to match `@--match--` in `@--match--` or just `@--match`? Also, what is the regex flavor?

Comment: Just guessing: try `\B(?<!\/)@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`. But please provide feedback for the above questions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your suggestion seems to work great. I've provided edits for clarity, but if you submit an answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b*` pattern makes no sense because `\b` requires a word boundary position and `*` makes it optional, thus, making it match nothing, making it totally redundant in the pattern. That is why it makes no sense making zero-width assertions (like anchors, word boundaries, lookarounds) optional.

You need

```
\B(?<!/)@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%28%3F%3C!%2F%29%40%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_-%5D%2B&i=%40match%2C%0D%0ACheck%20out%20this%20link!%20https%3A%2F%2Fsomeurl.com%2F%40nomatch%2Ftest.%20This%20is%20some%20text%20and%20some%20more%20text%20and%20some%20more%20text.%0D%0AWhat%20will%20it%20do%20with%20myemail%40nomatch.net%3F%0D%0AThis%20is%20a%20mention%20for%20%40match.%20This%20is%20another%20mention%20for%2C%20%40MaTch.%20%40__ma-tch__%20is%20awesome.%20So%20is%20%40--match--%2C%20%40ma_tch%2C%20and%20%40_MATCH.%0D%0AAnd%20let%27s%20not%20forget%20%40__match__.%0D%0ASincerely%2C%0D%0A%40match)

**Details**

- `\B`  - a location that is not a word boundary
- `(?<!/)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `/` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+` - 1+ ASCII letters, digits, underscores or hyphens.

In C# code, you may use

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"\B(?<!/)@[\w-]+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

where [`RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netcore-3.1) will make `\w` only match ASCII letters, digits and `_`, i.e. same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.